# Laravel form submission sending to the wrong route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a very simple form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['complete.order']]) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('F j, Y ')) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('web_token', $order->web_token) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Place this order', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I visit the page, this renders as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site.localhost/place-order" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="kc6d4XoZ78RvJNtQbN8lavpLP7e1lI7rTGBvbeIP">
    <input name="date" type="hidden" value="December 21, 2018 ">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="15">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Place this order">
</form>
```

Here are the relevant routes:

```
Route::get('/orders/form', 'OrdersController@viewform')->name('orderform');
Route::post('/orders/review', 'OrdersController@review')->name('orders.review');
Route::post('/place-order', 'OrdersController@store')->name('complete.order');
Route::resource('/orders', 'OrdersController', ['except'=>['edit', 'update', 'destroy', 'show', 'store']])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/orders/{order}', 'OrdersController@show')->name('orders.show');
```

When I click on the submit button, I'm directed to `site.localhost/orders/review`, which according to the debug bar is being passed to as a GET request, not POST.

I can't figure out why this is happening. The form should be going to `site.localhost/place-order`, which currently just outputs `return('place')` for testing.

The code in `OrdersController@show` currently outputs `return('show')`. I've done the same across all of the OrdersController methods for testing.

Adding `php artisan route` output

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                           | Name                  | Action                                                                 | Middleware                                           |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                             |                       | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _debugbar/assets/javascript   | debugbar.assets.js    | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@js                       | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\DebugbarEnabled,Closure |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _debugbar/assets/stylesheets  | debugbar.assets.css   | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@css                      | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\DebugbarEnabled,Closure |
|        | DELETE    | _debugbar/cache/{key}/{tags?} | debugbar.cache.delete | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\CacheController@delete                   | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\DebugbarEnabled,Closure |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _debugbar/clockwork/{id}      | debugbar.clockwork    | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenHandlerController@clockwork          | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\DebugbarEnabled,Closure |
|        | GET|HEAD  | _debugbar/open                | debugbar.openhandler  | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenHandlerController@handle             | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\DebugbarEnabled,Closure |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                      |                       | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | confirm-account/{token}       |                       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                             | web                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                          | home                  | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                         | login                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest                                            |
|        | POST      | login                         |                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest                                            |
|        | POST      | logout                        | logout                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | my-account                    | my-account.index      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                              | web,auth                                             |
|        | POST      | my-account                    | my-account.store      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                              | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | my-account/create             | my-account.create     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                             | web,auth                                             |
|        | PUT|PATCH | my-account/{my_account}       | my-account.update     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                             | web,auth                                             |
|        | DELETE    | my-account/{my_account}       | my-account.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                            | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | my-account/{my_account}       | my-account.show       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                               | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | my-account/{my_account}/edit  | my-account.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                               | web,auth                                             |
|        | POST      | orders                        | orders.store          | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@store                            | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders                        | orders.index          | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@index                            | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders/create                 | orders.create         | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@create                           | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders/form                   | orderform             | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@viewform                         | web                                                  |
|        | POST      | orders/review                 | orders.review         | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@review                           | web                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | orders/{order}                | orders.show           | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@show                             | web                                                  |
|        | POST      | password/email                | password.email        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest                                            |
|        | POST      | password/reset                |                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset                | password.request      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}        | password.reset        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest                                            |
|        | POST      | place-order                   | complete.order        | App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController@store                            | web                                                  |
|        | POST      | register                      |                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                      | register              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest                                            |
|        | POST      | user/store                    | user.store            | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                              | web                                                  |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Run a `php artisan route:list` and post the results. I think the problem is in the `except` part. According to the documentation you should use `->except([])`, the syntax you are using was valid until 5.5: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes. Also `/orders/{order}` should be above the `resource`.

Comment: tried sending to a url ? 

`{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}`

Comment: @azeós - added the output for you. I've tried reordering the `/orders/{order}` and also disabling it temporarily and it's having no impact.

Comment: @NeonEmmanuel - I don't think that's the issue as it's outputting to HTML with the correct path for the form. Tried it anyhow just to be sure and no change

Comment: As you can see, there's no `place-order` in the route list. But there's a `orders.store` and it shouldn't. Try disabling the `Route::resource`. Did you try the `->except([])` syntax? Could you post the complete route file? Maybe you ran a `php artisan route:cache`, try `php artisan route:clear`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#route-caching

Comment: sorry @azeós - I changed it to `place-order` to test that it wasn't getting stuck with the other naming conventions for `orders` and didn't save before running. I've updated to show the corrected list. The form is currently running on one of the `route::resource` entries, so disabling it is difficult.   `route:cache` throws an error "Uses Closure". ran `route:clear` with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm a complete and utter idiot.

The problem was that I was using a custom request for validation, which this route didn't meet. So it was actually returning the page back with errors, but since I didn't realize this it wasn't showing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is generated because you are using `Route::resource`, this route defines, `index`, `create`, `store`, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` routes for your controller and you're trying to overwrite the `store` route:

```
Route::post('/place-order', 'OrdersController@store')->name('complete.order');
```

You can use change your form code like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['orders.store']]) !!}
```

Or you can create a new function in your controller:

```
public function newfucntion(Request $request)
{
    //All your code here
}
```

Then create the new route:

```
Route::post('/place-order', 'OrdersController@newFunction')->name('complete.order');
```

And then change your form like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['complete.order']]) !!}
```